# Elixir: bound multiple variables in the conditions

Tags: elixir

In a situation to assign variables in the conditions:

```elixir
color = ""
unit = ""
case name do
  "Apple" ->
    color = "Red"
    unit = "kg"
  "Pear" ->
    color = "Green"
    unit = "each"
  _ ->
    color = "black"
    unit = "each"
end

%{name: name, color: color, unit: unit}
```

In the code above, it needs to state the variable in front. I don't think it's a nice code, and ideas?

Answer can use if/else for true/false, or use case for multiple conditions.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ assignment inside the `cond/2` clause makes no sense because of scoping: the value gets immediately discarded.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the scope of variable binding in Elixir. My code is totally wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially try this code:

```
{color, unit} = case name do
  "Apple" -> {"Red", "kg"}
  "Pear"  -> {"Green", "each"}
  _       -> {"black", "each"}
end
```

Would be more idiomatic

Comment: Tuple looks good. Only problem is that the order is important, and not clear for the name. My last line of code is the return. How about directly return in the condition? i.e. `%{name: name, color: "Red", unit: "Kg"}`

Comment: One of the reason I didn't use this, is that part of the values are same. For my example, the name expression is same. If returning in the condition, it will appear in each of them.

Comment: Besides being more idiomatic, this code works and the code in the question does not.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response! Regarding your first question @Stephen - yes, if that suits you better, you can make the `case` expression return map directly - no problem with that. Regarding your second question - trying to clean the code up to avoid duplication is one thing, but making it explicit and actually make it easier to understand and reason about is something else, and quite frankly - I would opt out for a bit more verbose code, but the one that is obvious to the reader. This touches back to your question - does returning map make it easier to read it? Do it! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with multiple function clauses:

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def color("Apple" = name), do: as_map(name, "Red", "kg")
  def color("Pear" = name), do: as_map(name, "Green", "each")
  def color(name), do: as_map(name, "black", "kg")

  def as_map(name, color, unit), do: %{name: name, color: color, unit: unit}
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(1)> Example.color("Apple")
%{color: "Red", name: "Apple", unit: "kg"}
iex(2)> Example.color("Pear")
%{color: "Green", name: "Pear", unit: "each"}
iex(3)> Example.color("Orange")
%{color: "black", name: "Orange", unit: "kg"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use functions and matching:

```
defp name_color_unit("Apple" = name), do: %{name: name, color: "Red", unit: "kg"}
defp name_color_unit("Pear" = name), do: %{name: name, color: "Green", unit: "each"}
defp name_color_unit(name), do: {name: name, color: "black", unit: "each"}
%{name: name, color: color, unit: unit} = name_color_unit(name)
```